# Clicking on next should send to next page

Tags: php, html

When any person clicks on any payment icon, then clicks `Next`, I want to send them on to the next page. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="paymentCont">
            <div class="headingWrap">
                <h3 class="headingTop text-center">Select Your Payment Method</h3>  
                <p class="text-center">Created with bootsrap button and using radio button</p>
            </div>
            <div class="paymentWrap">
                <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn paymentMethod active">
                        <div class="method visa"></div>
                        <input type="radio" name="options" checked> 
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                        <div class="method master-card"></div>
                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                        <div class="method amex"></div>
                        <input type="radio" name="options">
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                        <div class="method vishwa"></div>
                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                        <div class="method ez-cash"></div>
                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                    </label>

                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="footerNavWrap clearfix">
                <div class="btn btn-success pull-left btn-fyi">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    CONTINUE SHOPPING
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi">
                    Next
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahamad please specify your question properly and try to change the title .

Comment: what's the status of the question? an answer was provided. If it solved the question, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: there's also no "php" here; which makes the question unclear. If you want people to write that for you, it makes it "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and add a submit button

```
     <div class="paymentWrap">
                    <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <form action="somepage.php" method="POST">
                        <label class="btn paymentMethod active">
                            <div class="method visa"></div>
                            <input type="radio" name="options" checked> 
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                            <div class="method master-card"></div>
                            <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                            <div class="method amex"></div>
                            <input type="radio" name="options">
                        </label>
                         <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                            <div class="method vishwa"></div>
                            <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                            <div class="method ez-cash"></div>
                            <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" />
                      </form>
                    </div>        
                </div>
```